# SQL Error while updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have encountered an error and I do not know what is wrong with my code. Can someone help me?

> Error: UPDATE users SET voornaam = Test, achternaam = Test2, mail = test@test.com, tel = ,adres = , geslacht = man, bestuur = 0, tc = 0, ic = 0, jec = 0, rvr = , instructeur = 0, webmaster = 0 WHERE id = 1
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'adres = , geslacht = man, bestuur = 0, tc = 0, ic = 0, jec = 0, rvr = , instruct' at line 1

```
$id = $_GET['u'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET voornaam = $voornaam, achternaam = $achternaam,
        mail = $mailadres, tel = $tel, adres = $adres, geslacht = $geslacht,
        bestuur = $bestuur, tc = $tc, ic = $ic, jec = $jec, rvr = $rvr, 
        instructeur = $instructeur, webmaster = $webmaster WHERE id = ".$id."";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't set the value for `$tel` and `$adres`, are they empty? Consider using quotes on the strings (like this `voornaam = '$voornaam'`) just for sake of testing. But in reality, a preparedStatement should be used.

Comment: Your $adres is empty, your query `adres = `, gives error, if they are empty strings, it should be in qoutes like this: `adres = '$adres'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` 
           SET `voornaam` = '$voornaam', 
             `achternaam` = '$achternaam', 
                   `mail` = '$mailadres', 
                    `tel` = '$tel', 
                  `adres` = '$adres', 
               `geslacht` = '$geslacht', 
                `bestuur` = '$bestuur', 
                     `tc` = '$tc', 
                     `ic` = '$ic', 
                    `jec` = '$jec', 
                    `rvr` = '$rvr', 
            `instructeur` = '$instructeur', 
              `webmaster` = '$webmaster' 
           WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

This way you are protected if there are empty fields anywhere. You should also make sure you sanitize all the entries you wish to insert in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You must quote ANY string like **'xxxx'** else empty strings are missing and string with spaces are see as 2 strings achternaam= van mueller is wrong but achternaam = 'van mueller' is ok and also achternaam=''

Answer (score 2):

You need add quote `'` around the updated value, like

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET voornaam = '$voornaam', achternaam = '$achternaam', mail = '$mailadres', tel = '$tel', adres = '$adres', geslacht = '$geslacht', bestuur = '$bestuur', tc = '$tc', ic = '$ic', jec = '$jec', rvr = '$rvr', instructeur = '$instructeur', webmaster = '$webmaster' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure that your variables are set before your query, then check them before you create sql query with `isset`:

```
if (!isset($a)) {
    $a = ''
}
```

and put your variables in quote:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET voornaam='$voornaam', achternaam='$achternaam',   
        mail='$mailadres', tel='$tel', adres='$adres', geslacht='$geslacht', 
        bestuur='$bestuur', tc='$tc', ic='$ic', jec='$jec', rvr='$rvr', 
        instructeur='$instructeur', webmaster='$webmaster' WHERE id='".$id."'";
```